# Grouping elements of a list into sublists when a row is blank

Tags: r

I want to use the blank row represented by `""` that exists in my list so I can group all the rows in between into sublists.

For example I have a long list that looks like this:

```
    > data
 [1] "data science"
 [2] "big data"
 [3] "machine learning"
 [4] "BI"
 [5] "analytics"
 [6] ""
 [7] "SAS" 
 [8] "R"
 [9] "Python"
[10] "Spark"
[11] ""
[12] "Hive"
[13] "PIG"
[14] "IMPALA"
....
```

And I want something like this:

```
 > output
 [[1]] [1] "data science" "big data" "machine learning" "BI" "analytics"
 [[2]] [1] "SAS" "R" "Python" "Spark"
 [[3]] [1] "Hive" "PIG" "IMPALA"
```

The indexation in my output is maybe wrong but overall it's what I want.

Maybe something with `split`would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `split` can help you. If you `cumsum` a logical vector it will break apart your original vector into groups. You then have to drop the first element because it is "". That's what `tail` does in the `lapply`:

```
set.seed(201)
x <- sample(letters, 20, replace = T)
x[c(6,12)] <- ""

> lapply(split(x, cumsum(x == "")), tail, -1)
$`0`
[1] "p" "p" "q" "r"

$`1`
[1] "v" "n" "g" "l" "t"

$`2`
[1] "p" "p" "n" "e" "t" "c" "j" "m"
```

Comment: Thanks! this does exactly what I want. what `-1` does in lapply?

Comment: `lapply` takes a vector and a function as the first two arguments. Each element of the vector is passed as the first argument of the function. Anything provided after the function is passed in as additional arguments. In this case, `tail` is passed each element of the split output as its first argument and -1 as its second argument. HTH